# Determine if a point reside inside a leaflet polygon

Tags: leaflet, polygon, point-in-polygon

Suppose I Draw a polygan using leaflet like in the follow demo:
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/

My question is how I can determine if a given point reside inside the polygon or not.

Comment: If the polygon is closed then you can orientate every segment (inside/outside). Drawing a half-line from any point to infinity will end up in odd or even number of segment intersections (always odd or always even for every direction): even number of intersections are points outside the polygon and odd are inside. Thus you may choose any direction e.g. the x-axis: check for intersecting segments on `[pt.x,pt.y]-[inf, pt.y]` (you can also bound the half-line to the bounding box of the polygon). There are of course ways to do this more efficiently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location

Comment: I ask if there are a method that let me determine the latitude and the longitude of a polygon, and then determine if the point is inside the polygon or not using javascript

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the Ray Casting algorithm for checking if a point (marker) lies inside of a polygon:

```
function isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, poly) {
    var polyPoints = poly.getLatLngs();       
    var x = marker.getLatLng().lat, y = marker.getLatLng().lng;

    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = polyPoints.length - 1; i < polyPoints.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = polyPoints[i].lat, yi = polyPoints[i].lng;
        var xj = polyPoints[j].lat, yj = polyPoints[j].lng;

        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
            && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }

    return inside;
};
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/6s1np2n4/) for example.

Original source for the code: https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon/blob/master/index.js

---

See also 2014's similar answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138512/287948

Comment: that worked although `poly.getLatLngs()` returns an array of arrays so the first line had to be
`var polyPoints = poly.getLatLngs()[0];`
If you want to support donut shaped polygons, you need another wrapping loop.

Answer (score 20):

Here is the modified(with @Sumit hints) version of @gusper answer that worked for me:(i had donuts)

```
function isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, poly) {
    var inside = false;
    var x = marker.getLatLng().lat, y = marker.getLatLng().lng;
    for (var ii=0;ii<poly.getLatLngs().length;ii++){
        var polyPoints = poly.getLatLngs()[ii];
        for (var i = 0, j = polyPoints.length - 1; i < polyPoints.length; j = i++) {
            var xi = polyPoints[i].lat, yi = polyPoints[i].lng;
            var xj = polyPoints[j].lat, yj = polyPoints[j].lng;

            var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
                && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
            if (intersect) inside = !inside;
        }
    }

    return inside;
};
```

Comment: This works for me for random shaped polygons. thanks

Answer (score 8):

I found that none of the above answers worked for counting markers within *non-contiguous* polygons. Here's an example polygon where the above functions returned 0 markers inside:

[image: Non-contiguous Polygon]

For anyone who needs to do that, the `Leaflet.PointInPolygon` package worked for me: https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon

It's a bit slow, but it seems to be accurate.