# know if a marker is contained within a polygon in ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a doubt, beyond looking for the code that solves my problem. Is it possible from the native `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` to perform this type of calculations? or should I import the javascript script from google maps? and would the google maps functions on the native google maps plugin? thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `poly.containsLocation()`
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/tree/master/documents/poly#containslocationlocation-path

```
marker.on("position_changed").subscribe((params: any[]) => {
  let latLng: ILatLng = params[0];  // or marker.getPosition();

  let contain: boolean = Poly.containsLocation(position, POLYGON_POINTS);
  marker.setIcon(contain ? "blue" : "red");
});
```

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/class/utilities/geometry/poly/containsLocation/README.md

[image]

Comment: thanks, I want to know something .. this code works in version 1 of ionic? and can it serve the same thing but using a circle? thank you very much.