# How to detect if point is inside a natural area (or other type) polygon with overpass?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to figure out how to detect if latitude/longitude pair (-25.70078,-54.44522) is inside a natural area polygon.

Is there a better solution ?

So far I have something like this:
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1h8D

This code gets me the nearest area but it also gets me the closest areas, which I don't want.

I need to know if the point is "in" (true) the specified area.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: turfjs and pointsWithinPolygon or [determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon)